# creating roles in database project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, database-project, createuser

I`m using database project in visual studio 2013(professional).

All other thing works great, but I`m facing the issue with create user command. even I have already created user for dbproj on server with all access. Even I have only import database in database project and try to build though it showing me error.

Below command showing me error. 
"Create user [dbproj] for Login [dbproj]".

Please help me out...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And when are you getting the error (when building, while publishing, when deploying a .dacpac...)?

Comment: I've ended up handling users/permissions in post-deploy scripts until MS realizes that those change from environment to environment and gives us an easier way to handle them: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/05/ssdt-setting-different-permissions-per.html  (not necessarily easy, but it's a one-time setup and not as hard to handle after that initial phase)

Comment: At the time of build (compiler showing me error).

Comment: @Peter: Thanks Peter. I know it works fine in the post deployment script. This scripts run for some cases. Can`t understand the problem.

Comment: @Keith :Error: dbproj this is not a valid user.

Comment: Are you missing the CREATE LOGIN statement for dbproj?

Comment: No that is all right. Create Login is in another file.

Comment: Is the Build Action of the Create Login script set to "Build"?

Comment: yes. Create login is also included in build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If same command I write into the postDeploymentScript then it works in my case.